# How to force object equivalence for keys in a Kotlin hashmap?

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap, key, equals

I have a class 'Foo' (not under my control) which I wish to use as a key in a kotlin (java) hashmap.
The problem is that the 'equals' method for 'Foo' does value equivalence.
For my situation value equivalence is too loose.
I need object equivalence.

What are the ways to force force the use of object equivalence on the keys?

I am thinking something like...

```kotlin
data class Foo(val prop: String)
data class Bar(val prop: String)

fun main() {
    val fooMap = mutableMapOf<Any, Bar>()

    val fooA = Foo("common value")
    val fooB = Foo("common value")

    fooMap[fooA] = Bar("different A")
    fooMap[fooB] = Bar("different B")
    println("${fooMap.keys} ${fooMap.values}")
}
```

This results in a fooMap with only one entry, when I expect two.

```
[Foo(prop=common value)] [Bar(prop=different B)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) - it is the same map, but which compares only references of the keys.

Also note, to effectively use regular HashMap, the key class must respect not only `equals`, but also `hashCode`.

Comment: Your answer is good, and I will probably use it.
I would prefer to use a kotlin map.

Comment: @phreed Kotlin's `Map` is an interface, you still need an implementation. On JVM, Kotlin's `mutableMapOf` returns a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (a `Map` implementation from the Java stdlib). [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) is just another implementation which happens to do exactly what you need. Why not use it?

Comment: @AterLux why the link to Android's doc instead of the standard Javadoc? It might give the wrong idea that `IdentityHashMap` is Android-only. Consider linking to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html

Comment: Wrapping the 'new IdentityHashmap()' in a 'mutableIdentityMapOf' function gives me some isolation from the JVM implementation detail. (I might want to use this in a kolin native context.)

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case and when targeting JVM, `IdentityHashMap` is probably the best choice, as suggested by @AterLux .

If we need multiplatform solution or we have a more generic case of changing the `equals()` logic of a third party class, we can simply use our own wrapper as a key:

```kotlin
data class FooKey(val foo: Foo) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = foo === (other as? FooKey)?.foo
}


fun main() {
    val fooMap = mutableMapOf<FooKey, Bar>()

    val fooA = Foo("common value")
    val fooB = Foo("common value")

    fooMap[FooKey(fooA)] = Bar("different A")
    fooMap[FooKey(fooB)] = Bar("different B")
    println("${fooMap.keys} ${fooMap.values}")
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `hashCode()` too. (This looks like a rare was where you _don't_ have to override it as well — but it would be helpful to spell out why, and remind people that you _do_ need to do so in most other cases.)

Answer (score 0):

I will be using @AterLux answer but I am posting what I had been using for comments.

```kotlin
data class Identity<T>(private val delegate: T) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return delegate === other
    }
}
fun <K,V> mutableIdentityMapOf(): MutableMap<Identity<K>,V> {
    return mutableMapOf()
}


data class Foo(val prop: String)
data class Bar(val prop: String)

fun main() {
    val fooMap = mutableIdentityMapOf<Foo, Bar>()

    val fooA = Foo("common value")
    val fooB = Foo("common value")

    fooMap[Identity(fooA)] = Bar("different A")
    fooMap[Identity(fooB)] = Bar("different B")
    println("${fooMap.keys} ${fooMap.values}")
}
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake. You need to compare to `other.delegate` (after casting).